Rendering really heavy meshes
I'm a beginner trying to create a render of a scene using about a dozen obj photogrammetry tiles that are extremely heavy. My blend file is about 7gb at the moment.
Every time I try to load them all Blender crashes. I was hoping someone might be able to provide advice on how to optimise the way they display (preferably non-destructively) in object mode so I can see them all and create my view. And is there some way I can then render and save an image without having to go to the review window first? I don't mind if it needs to run all night. But at the moment when I try to open the render window Blender crashes.
Thanks in advance.

First step would be to clean them up, either with manual retopo or decimation, then baking the HP to the LP to get the normal data, and then applying those as a material. Right now all the detail on your meshes is coming from the verts themselves, you gotta find a way to transfer that to texture/material first thing to optimize them. If all you're doing is just rendering them in Blender then you might just be able to decimate them with "Preserve UVs" enabled and it could work. Decimation just has potential to jack up shading or the UVs so it might not be as clean as HP > LP baking.

You can read more about the process here

Thank you @Jakemoyo! I'll give that a go
